# THREE.js I want to object children assign variable, and loop list but not working

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, three.js

I want to binding variable object3D (for url) file. so I render arrray list map to children name.

You can see render method, i want to ul tag children name list, but this component rendered no data

and button click event, state vis assigned array for children list. and console.log(vis) is alright.

but render method {thsi.state.vis.length > 0 ? ...} is not working

I want to assign variable and checkbox checked is child visible true or false.

```
let scene;
let viscera = [];

function loadObj(url) {
  const objLoader = new THREE.OBJLoader();
  objLoader.load(
    url,
    function(object) {
      console.log(object);
      let mesh = object;
      scene.add(object);
      mesh.position.set(0, 2, 0);
      mesh.scale.set(2, 2, 2);

      object.traverse(child => {
        if (child instanceof THREE.Object3D) {
          viscera.push(child);
          const liver = child.getObjectByName('Liver_Liver.001');
          const stomach = child.getObjectByName('Stomach_Stomach.001');
          // if (liver && stomach) {
          //   liver.visible = false;
          //   stomach.visible = false;
          // }
        }
      })
      console.log(viscera);
    },
    function(xhr) {
      console.log((xhr.loaded / xhr.total) * 100 + "% loaded");
    },
    // called when loading has errors
    function(error) {
      console.log("An error happened" + error);
    });
}

class ObjectLoader extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      vis: viscera,
      get: false
    }
  }

  componentDidMount() {  
    const width = this.mount.clientWidth;
    const height = this.mount.clientHeight;
    scene = new THREE.Scene();
    this.camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(75, width / height, 0.1, 2000);
    this.camera.position.z = 8;

    this.renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({ antialias: true });
    this.renderer.setClearColor("#263238");
    this.renderer.setSize(width, height);
    this.mount.appendChild(this.renderer.domElement);
    // const geometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry(5, 5, 5);
    // const material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
    //   color: "#0F0",
    //   wireframe: true
    // });
    // this.cube = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
    // scene.add(this.cube);

    const controls = new OrbitControls(this.camera, this.renderer.domElement);
    controls.enableDamping = true;
    controls.dampingFactor = 0.25;
    controls.enableZoom = true;


    //LIGHTS
    const keyLight = new THREE.DirectionalLight(new THREE.Color('hsl(30, 100%, 75%)'), 1.0);
    keyLight.position.set(-100, 0, 100);

    const fillLight = new THREE.DirectionalLight(new THREE.Color('hsl(240, 100%, 75%)'), 0.75);
    fillLight.position.set(100, 0, 100);

    const backLight = new THREE.DirectionalLight(0xffffff, 1.0);
    backLight.position.set(100, 0, -100).normalize();

    scene.add(keyLight);
    scene.add(fillLight);
    scene.add(backLight);

    // load Object
    this.animate();
    loadObj(this.props.url);
}

  componentWillUnmount() {
    this.stop();
    this.mount.removeChild(this.renderer.domElement);
  }

  getViscera = (vis) => {
    this.props.getViscera(vis);
  }

  start = () => {
    if (!this.frameId) {
      this.frameId = requestAnimationFrame(this.animate);
    }
  };

  stop = () => {
    cancelAnimationFrame(this.frameId);
  };

  animate = () => {
    this.renderScene();
    this.frameId = window.requestAnimationFrame(this.animate);
  };

  renderScene = () => {
    if (this.renderer) this.renderer.render(scene, this.camera);
  };

  // handleViscera = () => {
  //   for (let i = 0; i < viscera.length; i++) {
  //     console.log(viscera[i].name);
  //   }
  // }

  onLoad = () => {
    this.renderScene();
    //start animation
    this.start();
  };

  onProgress = xhr => {
    console.log((xhr.loaded / xhr.total) * 100 + "% loaded");
  };

  // Function called when download errors
  onError = error => {
    console.log("An error happened" + error);
  };

  // getChildren = () => {
  //   this.setState({
  //     get: true
  //   })
  //   if (this.state.vis && this.state.get === true) {
  //     return (
  //       <ul>
  //         {this.state.vis.map(item => {
  //           console.log(item);
  //           <li key={item}>{item.name}</li>
  //         })}
  //       </ul>
  //     )
  //   }
  // }


  render() {
    return (
      <div className="objLoader">
        <div
          style={{ width: "500px", height: "500px" }}
          ref={mount => {
            this.mount = mount;
          }}
        />
        <h2>Children</h2>
        <button className="children-btn" onClick={() => this.getViscera(this.state.vis)}>Get Children</button>
        {
          this.state.vis.length > 0 ? 
          <ul>
            {this.state.vis.map(v => {
              <li>{v.name}</li>
            })}
          </ul>
          : <div>no data</div>
        }
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```